# How to make deep nest resources in Laravel filament

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

- I am using filament php as a dashboard
- I have the following relations in my codebase

`Material Selection > Quotation > Addendums`

- So material selection has many quotations and Quotation Has Many addendums.
- I Am trying to represent this as resources in filament
- I can’t use relation manager here because relation manager nest only
  one resource , so it ends like this `MaterialSelection > Quotations`
- So is there any way to add nested resources in filament
- So I can access Material Selection view page then I can see a button
  redirects me to the listing page of quotations and whenever I open
  the quotation view page I can see a button that redirects me to
  addendums listing page and so on and each one of these is a full resource.
- so I can make use of everything that the resource provide ?

Thanks all

I can do that by making custom livewire pages but it would be great if there is any workaround this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I struggled with this also, what you do is create the separate resources as normal.

Then inside the first resource, you can place a link inside the actions, table method:

```php
->actions([
    Action::make('quotations')->url(fn ($record): string => url('admin/materials/quotations/'.$record->id)),
    Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
])
```

Next if you want the quotation to be hidden from the sidarbar

```php
protected static bool $shouldRegisterNavigation = false;
```

specify the slug

```
protected static ?string $slug = 'materials/quotations';
```

In order to only load the related records:

```php
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
    return parent::getEloquentQuery()->where('material_id', request('record'));
}
```

Also the routes need to be updated

```php
public static function getPages(): array
{
    return [
        'index'           => ListQuotations::route('/'),
        'edit'            => EditQuotation::route('/{record}/edit'),
        'quotations'         => ListQuotations::route('/{record}'),
        'quotations.create'  => CreateQuotation::route('/{record}/create'),
    ];
}
```

you will need to do these steps for each resource you want to link.

Here's a demo using courses, modules, units resources https://github.com/dcblogdev/filament-courses-demo/tree/main/app/Filament/Resources

Comment: I get 404 when I try this.

Comment: Lookup the correct routes for your resources using  `php artisan route:list`